# NiFi Jolt Specification for array input

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have the following input in Nifi Jolt Specification processor:

```json
[
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "paramA",
        "value": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "id": "paramB",
        "value": 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "paramA",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "paramB",
    "value": 2
  }
]
```

Can you explain how I have to do?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to reach the objects of the `values` array which are nested within seperate object signs (`{}`). A `"*"` notation is needed in order to cross them over per each individual `values` array, and then use another `"*"` notation for indexes of those arrays while choosing `""` as the counterpart values in order to grab nothing but the sub-objects such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "values": {
          "*": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]